# Docker build unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: npm, dockerfile, registry

I am running docker build for the following Dockerfile

```
ARG UID=101
ARG GID=101
ARG ENV='env3'

FROM node:16-alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm i
RUN npm audit fix --audit-level=none

COPY ./ /app/

EXPOSE 3001
ENV PORT 3001
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

and getting the error

```
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-7.24.2.tgz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

When I run `npm i` locally I have no issue, having a look online it seems to be an issue with SSL,  I tried to disable in Dockerfile and this did nothing.

Any ideas how to solve this?